# Chrome on OSX display error

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Why does my Google Chrome browser (on OSX) do this to text on some websites? Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: That's because the site you're visiting doesn't respect the W3C standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something strange set for your default encoding.  Try the setting under Preferences → Under the Hood → Change Font and Language Settings → Default Encoding, set it to "Western (ISO-8859-1)".

On individual pages, you can also try the View menu → Text Encoding → Auto Detect.